# Density and refractive index of Water/sugar solution

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, refraction, density

I can't find a correlation or equation for refractive index of water and sugar solution of known density. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: Second google result...http://homepages.gac.edu/~cellab/chpts/chpt3/table3-2.html

Comment: Refractive index vs concentration is certainly easy to find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this measure is used by winemakers to solve for sugar content of grape juice.
search for "refractometer" under winemaking supplies and equipment.